# How to search through values in a HashMap to find the highest value, and return both that value and key?

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap, compare, key

I'm writing a code that requires a comparison of values, but am fairly new to HashMaps and am not sure how to search through all of the values saved.

What I'm trying to do is find the highest value of all of the saved values. I want it to go through until the first condition passes, save both that value and key, and continue through until a new value passes through the if-statement condition.

```
double highestNum = 0.0; // 0 set to the default lowest value; saves highest value
String highestKey = ""; // used to save the key assosciated w/ highest value

for (String high : quantity_hash.keySet()) {
    if (quantity_hash.get(high) > highestNum) {
        highestKey = high;
    }
}
```

As of now (I believe), my code will search through the values until the if-statement passes. It will then save that key and value, and then it stops. Any suggestions?

edit: I've looked at previous questions, and they seem to just try to find a key associated with a set value, whereas I'm trying to compare all of the values, and save the keys associated with those. highestNum and highestKey should get rewritten multiple times, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks AntonH for the correction with the "Double.MIN_VALUE." This helps in case the value is a negative. Turns out I forgot a line of code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a slight modification to store the high value:

```
double highestNum = 0.0; // 0 set to the default lowest value
String highestKey = ""; // used to save the key assosciated w/ highest value
for (String key : quantityHash.keySet()) {
    double value = quantityHash.get(key);  // ADDED LINE
    if (value > highestNum) {              // MODIFIED LINE
        highestKey = key;
        highestNum = value;                // ADDED LINE
    }
}
```

This will loop through and look at all the values.  Your code will loop through too, but you'll only have the key for the highest value; you didn't update `highestNum`, so it remains at 0.0.

Comment: Gah, such a stupid mistake! Forgetting to store the highest value again. One line of code, of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the `highestNum` variable. Modify de `for body as:

```
double current_value = quantity_hash.get(high);
if ( current_value > highestNum) {
    highestKey = high;
    highestNum = current;
}
```

As AntonH commented, it is a good practice to use `Double.MIN_VALUE` instead of `0` as starting value just in case all the values are negative.